# Xattrs are not supported

Tags: linux, xattr

I am trying to perform a little testing of `XATTRs`. I recompiled my kernel with  ALL the XATTRs enabled.

Now, when I include the header of xattrs :

```
#include <attr/xattr.h>
```

I receive an error **no such file or directory**. I am using UBUNTU 11.10 64 bit system, and I cannot understand why XATTRs are not supported ?

Answer (score 18):

Adding support in the kernel doesn't make the header files magically appear on their own! Install libattr1-dev.

Comment: I have already installed it, but the problem hasn't been passed yet.

Comment: on centos that's libattr-devel

Answer (score 0):

"attr/xattr.h" was replaced by "sys/xattr.h" so try this instead #include <sys/xattr.h>